# R - counts of factors in filtered datasets

Tags: r

I have a dataset in the following format -

```
Item Year
A    2018
B    2018
B    2019
A    2017
Z    2019
```

I select items only from 2018 using:

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>% filter(Year == "2018")
```

Now, when I get the counts of items using table(), there's a problem. The output looks like -

```
table(data2$Item)

A B Z
1 1 0
```

I don't understand why Z is included here. There are no Z items in data2. It messes up summary statistics.

Is there any way to prevent items from the original dataset being included? I tried filtering the original dataset without dplyr, but table() still returns the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'Item' is `factor`, it could be the unused levels.  If we check the `levels`, it still exist

```
levels(data2$Item)
#[1] "A" "B" "Z"
```

Either we can use `droplevels`

```
table(droplevels(data2$Item))
#  A B 
#1 1
```

Or specify the `.drop` in `count`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    filter(Year == "2018") %>% 
    count(Item, .drop = TRUE)
#  Item n
#1    A 1
#2    B 1
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "Z"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2017L, 
2019L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```